# nginx ngx_http_secure_link_module and php video streaming

Tags: php, nginx, streaming, mp4

I have for hours been trying to understand and figure out how this is working, and searched and tried a lot, but still.... No hair left on my head :(

Sources for trial and errors
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html#variables
[Secure pseudo-streaming flv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848919/secure-pseudo-streaming-flv-files/8863219#8863219)
[Nginx secure link module not working with php files but working on static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468743/nginx-secure-link-module-not-working-with-php-files-but-working-on-static-files)
[nginx HttpSecureLinkModule php example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30065870/nginx-httpsecurelinkmodule-php-example)

The question is how do I get Nginx and php to make a timed encrypted link to play a video?

The final output sould be looking like

```
http://domain.tld/videos/529d86c4ff560cb559df7eb794aeb4b1/56f5bec4/5/4/d/f/e/54dfee5c43e6e.mp4
```

real path for this video is

```
/var/www/domain.tld/media/videos/5/4/d/f/e/54dfee5c43e6e.mp4
```

The php snippet that should be left unaltered if posible, since it will be updated from time to time from the developer.

```
//generate lighttpd hash
function getMediaLink($filename) {
  global $modsec_secret; // example: s3cr3tk3y (from your lighttpd config)
  global $modsec_url; // example: http://media.asfd.com/dl/ with trailing slash
  $filename = rawurldecode($filename);
  $f = "/".$filename;
  $t = time();
  $t_hex = sprintf("%08x", $t);
  $m = md5($modsec_secret.$f.$t_hex);
  $link = $modsec_url.$m.'/'.$t_hex.$f;
  return $link;
}
```

And to the NginX conf file i have this head:

```
    server {
        listen       80; # http2;
        server_name  localhost;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        #charset koi8-r;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        root   /var/www/domain.tld;

        location / {

..... (the latest attempt)

     location /videos/ {
        secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 "secret$uri$arg_e";

        root /var/www/domain.tld/media/videos; #physical real path
        if ($secure_link = "") {
                return 403;
        }
        if ($secure_link = 0) {
                return 410;
        }
    }
```

Could some one please try to tell me how to make this happen, but maybe more important why, in a passion that mae me understand how and why?

Comment: If you want to stream something, you could use the Xsendfile module instead (and do the authentication with PHP).

Comment: Thx for your reply and suggestion. I have been messing a bit with it, but it would require me to make a lot of changes in several php scripts

Comment: It seems you don't have right location because right now **st** argument receives signature but **e** - timestamp.  Arguments are the part of URI at the right side. That URL should look as follows: /video/5/4/d/f/e/54dfee5c43e6e.mp4?st=abc&e=147. Can you explain your config, *529d86c4ff560cb559df7eb794aeb4b1* signature but *56f5bec4* some kind of time stamp?

Comment: Hi Anatoly. The 529d86c4ff560cb559df7eb794aeb4b1 should be the md5 sum of the secret string in my config file and the 56f5bec4 is as fare I understand the timestamp, but I'm not the one who made the php... I'm the one trying to make the NginX working with the php code.... but I have in my attempts noticed that the md5 from php vs nginx ain't equil

Comment: Nginx secure_link is quite simple, if md5 of original URL matched the signature it works, otherwise an error code is returned back. Timestamp doesn't look plausible. Make sure the signature is generated correctly and "secret" string is the same on php and Nginx both sides.

Comment: Hi http://stackoverflow.com/users/290338/anatoly thx for reply, but without the timestamp, isn't the url static again? just md5 hashed?